# Repository Pattern and multiple related core entities or business objects - one repository or more?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am looking at implementing the repository pattern (since what I came up with was 90% an implementation of it anyway), and have come across a design question - where I have two or more core business objects (for example, Business and Contact in a CRM app), the BO's can be strongly related or not related at all.

In this situation, should I implement one repository (CrmRepository for example, with .addBusiness(), .addContact() et al), or multiple repositories (BusinessRepository, ContactRepository each with their own .add(), .delete() et al).

What is the best practice in this situation?

The underlying DAL is EF4.

Regards

Moo

Comment: +1—partially for the question and partially for the CaH avatar ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We have been doing a lot of thinking recently at my work and came across a few articles that helped us visualize and design our repositories in a consistent manner.

From what we found out one of the better practices is to create one repository per aggregate root.  An aggregate root would be an Entity type where you need to reference that entity type to reach child value types.  Only an Entity type could be queried from the database and any child Value types would need to be traversed from the Entity.

With your information in your question it seems like a Business would be an aggregate root and thus an Entity Type and would require its own repository.  Since Contact can live independently that might be an aggregate root as well.  Both objects could have references to each other and use a repository to load up the Businesses from a Contact or Load up the Contacts from a Business via its respective repository.

I have been doing a lot of reading recently so i hope I made some sense in my thought process.

Some links

[Aggregate Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639773/design-aggregate-root-properly)

[Entities, Value Objects, Aggregates and Roots](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/05/20/entities-value-objects-aggregates-and-roots.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

I totally agree with Mark on this, but to add a little more.  As you look at the benefits of creating a Generic Repository, the common patter is IRepository and Repository.  One thing I've found to be much more useful, brought to light by Jeremy D. Miller (can't find the reference) is having generics at the method level.

So my IReposity will have methods like this:

```
T FindByKey<T>(int key);
IEnumerable<T> FindAll();
T FindBy<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
void Update<T>(entity);
```

Then, depending on your philosophy, you can pass around the Repository class and query it directly, or make your Repository implementation abstract and force it's use to be encapsulated by an explicit repository, like this:

```
CrmRepository : Repository
{
   FindByCustomerId(int customerId)
   { return FindByKey<Customer>(customerId);}
}
```

Comment: If you are inheriting Repository which inherits from IRepository ; how about Repository<T> instead and usage like CrmRepository : Repository<Customer> {//..}

Comment: @Corey, are you suggesting it is better to have method level generics rather than class/Repository level? I am using a class level Repository<T> right now, can you expand why method-only level might be better?

Comment: Never mind. I just realized that you basically cannot have just method level generics because that would anticipate the primary key being a certain type. So basically a Repository<T> is going to work better for any system which has more than one type (int or string etc) as the PK.