# How to apply transaction two service inside one controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a two model X and Y. For the models I also have a Service and Repository.

The structure is:

```
| App
|| Http
||| Controller
|||| XController
|||| YController.php

| Service
|| XService.php
|| YService.php

| Repository
|| XRepository.php
|| YRepository.php
```

Ok. Now I have a third controller Z (disconnected from the model).

```
| App
|| Http
||| Controller
|||| XController
|||| YController.php
|||| ZController.php <!--- THIS

| Service
|| XService.php
|| YService.php

| Repository
|| XRepository.php
|| YRepository.php
```

In the ZController I must recall the create method by two services (XService and YService).

```
class ZController extends Controller
{
    protected XService $XService;
    protected YService $YService;

    public function __construct(XService $XService, YService $YService)
    {
        $this->XService = $XService;
        $this->YService = $YService;
    }

    public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $x = $this->XService->create();
        $y = $this->YService->create();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that: if the service of $y fails (Exception), I must also delete the insertion of $x. If I enter the DB::transaction generates an error when it is a transaction grafted to others. What solution can I apply?

And, the try catch can i apply inside the repository or service? Or in both for particular situation?

Comment: transition? transation? you mean `transaction`?

Comment: Oh year sorry, i correct.

Comment: your problem is between having the repositories handle the transaction or the controller handle the transaction. kinda curious, why dont you just make another repository that handle transaction for both entities?

Comment: create another repository that does the same things you XRepositoy and YRepository does not seem right. Just call up the two services that already do the whole thing. At most you can create a ZService where I call XRepository and YReposytory (create) but it doesn’t solve my transaction problem.

Comment: thats why i said, "your problem is (...) or the controller handle the transaction." if you dont want additional repository, let the controller handle it. design pattern do need to accomodate needs. this kind of question draws a lot of opinions, there is no exact answer of "whats right." see [this dicussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327408/repository-pattern-and-multiple-related-core-entities-or-business-objects-one).

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn’t support multiple inheritance but by using Interfaces in PHP or using Traits in PHP instead of classes ,same Goes with Laravel ,If you Don't want to go through making repository ,then you can use simple traits for the task .